Pyomo IPOPT Collision Avoidance Violation
I am trying to use pyomo for nonlinear programming trajectory optimization.
I used simple UAV model to optimize for the minimum travel time trajectory from initial position to final position. I want to add a moving obstacle that is described by some waypoints and time.
waypoints = np.array([
        [100, 100, 30, 0],   # Start at time = 0, structure [x,y,z,time]
        [75, 75, 15, 3],     # Reach this point by time = 3 seconds
        [50, 50, 0, 5],      # Reach this point by time = 5 seconds
        [50, 50, 0, 12],     # Stay until time = 12 seconds
        [25, 25, 25, 17],    # Move to this point by time = 17 seconds
        [0, 0, 50, 20]       # Final position by time = 20 seconds
    ])

Notice that i want the obstacle to stay at the landing coordinate (50,50,0) for quite some time before move again to the final position.
The final position of the UAV is the landing coordinate (50,50,0). I implemented the collision avoidance constraint (see the code), but somehow the IPOPT solver said optimal solution found, even when the collision avoidance constraint is violated. The UAV keeps landing succesfully on top of the obstacle.
This is the collision avoidance part of the code. I suspect that the mistake is in the time mapping and synchronization between the UAV and the Obstacle, but I cannot figure out where the mistake is. I don't know if I have made a logical mistake. Please help me to figure out which mistake I've made, leading to this behavior.
# Constants for example, make sure these are defined in your code context
safety_distance = 20  # safety distance in meters
T_obstacle = 20  # total time for obstacle to complete its path based on the last waypoint time

# Obstacle waypoints
waypoints = np.array([
    [100, 100, 30, 0],   # Start at time = 0
    [75, 75, 15, 3],     # Reach this point by time = 3 seconds
    [50, 50, 0, 5],      # Reach this point by time = 5 seconds
    [50, 50, 0, 12],     # Stay until time = 12 seconds
    [25, 25, 25, 17],    # Move to this point by time = 17 seconds
    [0, 0, 50, 20]       # Final position by time = 20 seconds
])

# Extract positions and corresponding times from waypoints
positions = waypoints[:, :3]
times = waypoints[:, 3]

# Create interpolation functions using specified times
obstacle_x = interp1d(times, positions[:, 0], kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
obstacle_y = interp1d(times, positions[:, 1], kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
obstacle_z = interp1d(times, positions[:, 2], kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')

def scaled_time(m, t):
    return t * value(m.tf)

# Collision avoidance constraint using the time scaled by model.tf directly
def collision_avoidance_constraint(m, t):
    obs_t_value = scaled_time(m, t)
    distance_squared = ((m.x[t] - obstacle_x(obs_t_value))**2 + 
                        (m.y[t] - obstacle_y(obs_t_value))**2 + 
                        (m.z[t] - obstacle_z(obs_t_value))**2)
    print(f"Time {t}, Scaled Time {obs_t_value}, Distance Squared {distance_squared}, Safety Distance Squared {safety_distance**2}")
    return distance_squared >= safety_distance**2
model.collision_avoidance = Constraint(model.t, rule=collision_avoidance_constraint)

I want to keep m.tf as a variable, so maybe the use of value() is incorrect. But if I just use 't * m.tf', then I get the following error.
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint
collision_avoidance with index 0: ValueError: object arrays are not supported
ERROR: Constructing component 'collision_avoidance' from data=None failed:
        ValueError: object arrays are not supported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dtdav\anaconda3\envs\project\test.py", line 197, in <module>
    model.collision_avoidance = Constraint(model.t, rule=collision_avoidance_constraint)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dtdav\anaconda3\envs\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 568, in __setattr__
    self.add_component(name, val)
  File "C:\Users\dtdav\anaconda3\envs\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 1126, in add_component
    val.construct(data)
  File "C:\Users\dtdav\anaconda3\envs\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\constraint.py", line 800, in construct
    self._setitem_when_not_present(index, rule(block, index))
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dtdav\anaconda3\envs\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\initializer.py", line 316, in __call__
    return self._fcn(parent, idx)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\dtdav\anaconda3\envs\project\test.py", line 192, in collision_avoidance_constraint
    distance_squared = ((m.x[t] - obstacle_x(obs_t_value))**2 +
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dtdav\anaconda3\envs\Lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_polyint.py", line 80, in __call__
    x, x_shape = self._prepare_x(x)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dtdav\anaconda3\envs\Lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_polyint.py", line 92, in _prepare_x
    x = _asarray_validated(x, check_finite=False, as_inexact=True)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dtdav\anaconda3\envs\Lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 324, in _asarray_validated
    raise ValueError('object arrays are not supported')
ValueError: object arrays are not supported

This is the full code.
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import pandas as pd

# Constants
g = 9.81  # acceleration due to gravity in m/s^2
mass = 0.625  # mass in kg
Ix = Iy = Iz = 2.3e-3  # moment of inertia in kg*m^2

# Model setup
model = ConcreteModel()
model.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0, 1))
model.tf = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals, initialize=20)

# Position and velocity
model.x = Var(model.t, bounds=(0, 100))
model.y = Var(model.t, bounds=(0, 100))
model.z = Var(model.t, bounds=(0, 100))
model.vx = Var(model.t, bounds=(-5, 5))
model.vy = Var(model.t, bounds=(-5, 5))
model.vz = Var(model.t, bounds=(-5, 5))

# Angles and angular velocities
model.phi = Var(model.t, bounds=(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2))
model.theta = Var(model.t, bounds=(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2))
model.psi = Var(model.t, bounds=(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2))
model.p = Var(model.t, bounds=(-2, 2))
model.q = Var(model.t, bounds=(-2, 2))
model.r = Var(model.t, bounds=(-2, 2))

# Control inputs
model.U1 = Var(model.t, bounds=(-21, 21))
model.U2 = Var(model.t, bounds=(-0.67, 0.67))
model.U3 = Var(model.t, bounds=(-0.67, 0.67))
model.U4 = Var(model.t, bounds=(-0.11, 0.11))

# Derivative variables
model.x_dot = DerivativeVar(model.x, wrt=model.t)
model.y_dot = DerivativeVar(model.y, wrt=model.t)
model.z_dot = DerivativeVar(model.z, wrt=model.t)
model.vx_dot = DerivativeVar(model.vx, wrt=model.t)
model.vy_dot = DerivativeVar(model.vy, wrt=model.t)
model.vz_dot = DerivativeVar(model.vz, wrt=model.t)
model.phi_dot = DerivativeVar(model.phi, wrt=model.t)
model.theta_dot = DerivativeVar(model.theta, wrt=model.t)
model.psi_dot = DerivativeVar(model.psi, wrt=model.t)
model.p_dot = DerivativeVar(model.p, wrt=model.t)
model.q_dot = DerivativeVar(model.q, wrt=model.t)
model.r_dot = DerivativeVar(model.r, wrt=model.t)

# Differential equations

def _ode_x(m, t):
    return m.x_dot[t] == m.tf * m.vx[t]
model.ode_x = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_x)

def _ode_y(m, t):
    return m.y_dot[t] == m.tf * m.vy[t]
model.ode_y = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_y)

def _ode_z(m, t):
    return m.z_dot[t] == m.tf * m.vz[t]
model.ode_z = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_z)

def _ode_vx(m, t):
    return m.vx_dot[t] == m.tf * (cos(m.phi[t]) * sin(m.theta[t]) * cos(m.psi[t]) + sin(m.phi[t]) * sin(m.psi[t])) * m.U1[t] / mass
model.ode_vx = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_vx)

def _ode_vy(m, t):
    return m.vy_dot[t] == m.tf * (cos(m.phi[t]) * sin(m.theta[t]) * sin(m.psi[t]) - sin(m.phi[t]) * cos(m.psi[t])) * m.U1[t] / mass
model.ode_vy = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_vy)

def _ode_vz(m, t):
    return m.vz_dot[t] == m.tf * (-g + (cos(m.phi[t]) * cos(m.theta[t])) * m.U1[t] / mass)
model.ode_vz = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_vz)

def _ode_phi(m, t):
    return m.phi_dot[t] == m.tf * m.p[t]
model.ode_phi = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_phi)

def _ode_theta(m, t):
    return m.theta_dot[t] == m.tf * m.q[t]
model.ode_theta = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_theta)

def _ode_psi(m, t):
    return m.psi_dot[t] == m.tf * m.r[t]
model.ode_psi = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_psi)

def _ode_p(m, t):
    return m.p_dot[t] == m.tf * (m.U2[t] + m.q[t] * m.r[t] * (Iy - Iz)) / Ix
model.ode_p = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_p)

def _ode_q(m, t):
    return m.q_dot[t] == m.tf * (m.U3[t] + m.p[t] * m.r[t] * (Iz - Ix)) / Iy
model.ode_q = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_q)

def _ode_r(m, t):
    return m.r_dot[t] == m.tf * (m.U4[t] + m.p[t] * m.q[t] * (Ix - Iy)) / Iz
model.ode_r = Constraint(model.t, rule=_ode_r)

## Load data from CSV
#data = pd.read_csv('simulation_results.csv')
#
## Set up interpolation functions for each variable
#interpolators = {
#    var: interp1d(data['time'], data[var], kind='cubic', fill_value="extrapolate")
#    for var in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'vx', 'vy', 'vz', 'phi', 'theta', 'psi', 'p', 'q', 'r', 'U1', 'U2', 'U3', 'U4']
#}
#
## The actual time span of your data
#actual_start_time = data['time'].min()
#actual_end_time = data['time'].max()
#
## Set interpolated values as initial guesses
#for t in model.t:  # Iterate through the ContinuousSet
#    # Scale the time correctly to match the data timeline
#    scaled_time = actual_start_time + t * (actual_end_time - actual_start_time)
#
#    # Assign interpolated values to the model variables
#    model.x[t].set_value(interpolators['x'](scaled_time).item())  # Convert to scalar with .item()
#    model.y[t].set_value(interpolators['y'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.z[t].set_value(interpolators['z'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.vx[t].set_value(interpolators['vx'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.vy[t].set_value(interpolators['vy'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.vz[t].set_value(interpolators['vz'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.phi[t].set_value(interpolators['phi'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.theta[t].set_value(interpolators['theta'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.psi[t].set_value(interpolators['psi'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.p[t].set_value(interpolators['p'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.q[t].set_value(interpolators['q'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.r[t].set_value(interpolators['r'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.U1[t].set_value(interpolators['U1'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.U2[t].set_value(interpolators['U2'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.U3[t].set_value(interpolators['U3'](scaled_time).item())
#    model.U4[t].set_value(interpolators['U4'](scaled_time).item())

# Initial and final conditions
model.x[0].fix(30)
model.y[0].fix(30)
model.z[0].fix(20)
model.vx[0].fix(0)
model.vy[0].fix(0)
model.vz[0].fix(0)
model.phi[0].fix(0)
model.theta[0].fix(0)
model.psi[0].fix(0)
model.p[0].fix(0)
model.q[0].fix(0)
model.r[0].fix(0)

model.x[1].fix(50)
model.y[1].fix(50)
model.z[1].fix(0)
model.vx[1].fix(0)
model.vy[1].fix(0)
model.vz[1].fix(0)
model.phi[1].fix(0)
model.theta[1].fix(0)


# Constants for example, make sure these are defined in your code context
safety_distance = 20  # safety distance in meters
T_obstacle = 20  # total time for obstacle to complete its path based on the last waypoint time

# Obstacle waypoints
waypoints = np.array([
    [100, 100, 30, 0],   # Start at time = 0
    [75, 75, 15, 3],     # Reach this point by time = 3 seconds
    [50, 50, 0, 5],      # Reach this point by time = 5 seconds
    [50, 50, 0, 12],     # Stay until time = 12 seconds
    [25, 25, 25, 17],    # Move to this point by time = 17 seconds
    [0, 0, 50, 20]       # Final position by time = 20 seconds
])

# Extract positions and corresponding times from waypoints
positions = waypoints[:, :3]
times = waypoints[:, 3]

# Create interpolation functions using specified times
obstacle_x = interp1d(times, positions[:, 0], kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
obstacle_y = interp1d(times, positions[:, 1], kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
obstacle_z = interp1d(times, positions[:, 2], kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')

def scaled_time(m, t):
    return t * value(m.tf)

# Collision avoidance constraint using the time scaled by model.tf directly
def collision_avoidance_constraint(m, t):
    obs_t_value = scaled_time(m, t)
    distance_squared = ((m.x[t] - obstacle_x(obs_t_value))**2 + 
                        (m.y[t] - obstacle_y(obs_t_value))**2 + 
                        (m.z[t] - obstacle_z(obs_t_value))**2)
    print(f"Time {t}, Scaled Time {obs_t_value}, Distance Squared {distance_squared}, Safety Distance Squared {safety_distance**2}")
    return distance_squared >= safety_distance**2
model.collision_avoidance = Constraint(model.t, rule=collision_avoidance_constraint)



# Objective function to minimize energy or time
def objective_rule(m):
    return m.tf
model.objective = Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=minimize)

# Apply discretization
discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.collocation')
discretizer.apply_to(model, nfe=800, ncp=10, wrt=model.t, scheme='LAGRANGE-LEGENDRE')

solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.options.update({
    'halt_on_ampl_error': 'yes',
    'tol': 1e-6,
    'max_iter': 2000, 
    'print_level': 5,  # High verbosity for detailed solver output
    #'linear_solver': 'ma27'  # Recommended for larger-scale problems if available
})

result = solver.solve(model, tee=True)  # Execute the solver with console output

#critical_points = [t for t in sorted(model.t) if value(model.x[t]) == 50 and value(model.y[t]) == 50 and value(model.z[t]) <= 0.5]

for t in model.t:
    scaled_time = value(model.tf * t)
    ox = obstacle_x(scaled_time)
    oy = obstacle_y(scaled_time)
    oz = obstacle_z(scaled_time)
    distance_squared = (value(model.x[t]) - ox)**2 + (value(model.y[t]) - oy)**2 + (value(model.z[t]) - oz)**2
    print(f"Critical Time {scaled_time:.2f}: UAV Position ({value(model.x[t]):.2f}, {value(model.y[t]):.2f}, {value(model.z[t]):.2f})")
    print(f"Obstacle Position ({ox:.2f}, {oy:.2f}, {oz:.2f})")
    print(f"Distance squared to obstacle: {distance_squared:.2f} (Constraint satisfied: {distance_squared >= safety_distance**2})")


# Check solver status and results
if (result.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (result.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
    print("Solver found an optimal solution.")
elif result.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible:
    print("No feasible solution found.")
else:
    print("Solver status:", result.solver.status)
    print("Termination condition:", result.solver.termination_condition)


# Dictionary to hold the data
results_data = {
    'time': [],
    'x': [],
    'y': [],
    'z': [],
    'vx': [],
    'vy': [],
    'vz': [],
    'phi': [],
    'theta': [],
    'psi': [],
    'p': [],
    'q': [],
    'r': [],
    'U1': [],
    'U2': [],
    'U3': [],
    'U4': []
}

# Fill the dictionary with values from the model
for t in model.t:
    results_data['time'].append(t)
    results_data['x'].append(value(model.x[t]))
    results_data['y'].append(value(model.y[t]))
    results_data['z'].append(value(model.z[t]))
    results_data['vx'].append(value(model.vx[t]))
    results_data['vy'].append(value(model.vy[t]))
    results_data['vz'].append(value(model.vz[t]))
    results_data['phi'].append(value(model.phi[t]))
    results_data['theta'].append(value(model.theta[t]))
    results_data['psi'].append(value(model.psi[t]))
    results_data['p'].append(value(model.p[t]))
    results_data['q'].append(value(model.q[t]))
    results_data['r'].append(value(model.r[t]))
    results_data['U1'].append(value(model.U1[t]))
    results_data['U2'].append(value(model.U2[t]))
    results_data['U3'].append(value(model.U3[t]))
    results_data['U4'].append(value(model.U4[t]))

# Create a DataFrame from the dictionary
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results_data)

# Save to CSV (optional)
results_df.to_csv('C:/Users/dtdav/anaconda3/envs/project/simulation_results.csv', index=False)


import plotly.graph_objs as go
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


# Function to extract data from Pyomo model
def extract_data(var, model, obstacle_timeset):
    return np.array([value(var[t]) for t in obstacle_timeset])

# Extracting time and position data
time = np.array([t * value(model.tf) for t in model.t]) 
x = extract_data(model.x, model, model.t)
y = extract_data(model.y, model, model.t)
z = extract_data(model.z, model, model.t)
phi = extract_data(model.phi, model, model.t)
theta = extract_data(model.theta, model, model.t)
psi = extract_data(model.psi, model, model.t)



# Extracting time and position data for UAV
total_duration_uav = value(model.tf)  # Total duration of UAV flight in seconds
fps = 30  # Frames per second
total_frames_uav = int(fps * total_duration_uav)  # Make sure this is an integer
uniform_time_uav = np.linspace(0, total_duration_uav, total_frames_uav)

# Interpolating data for uniform time steps for UAV
interp_x = interp1d(time, x, kind='linear')(uniform_time_uav)
interp_y = interp1d(time, y, kind='linear')(uniform_time_uav)
interp_z = interp1d(time, z, kind='linear')(uniform_time_uav)
interp_phi = interp1d(time, phi, kind='linear')(uniform_time_uav)
interp_theta = interp1d(time, theta, kind='linear')(uniform_time_uav)
interp_psi = interp1d(time, psi, kind='linear')(uniform_time_uav)


# For the obstacle
total_frames_obstacle = fps * T_obstacle  # Frames based on fixed obstacle duration
uniform_time_obstacle = np.linspace(0, T_obstacle, total_frames_obstacle)

# Interpolating obstacle data for uniform time steps
interp_obs_x = obstacle_x(uniform_time_obstacle)
interp_obs_y = obstacle_y(uniform_time_obstacle)
interp_obs_z = obstacle_z(uniform_time_obstacle)

def rotation_matrix(phi, theta, psi):
    # Calculate rotation matrix based on Euler angles
    Rz = np.array([
        [np.cos(psi), -np.sin(psi), 0],
        [np.sin(psi), np.cos(psi), 0],
        [0, 0, 1]
    ])
    Ry = np.array([
        [np.cos(theta), 0, np.sin(theta)],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [-np.sin(theta), 0, np.cos(theta)]
    ])
    Rx = np.array([
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, np.cos(phi), -np.sin(phi)],
        [0, np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi)]
    ])
    return Rz @ Ry @ Rx

def update_uav_shape(x, y, z, phi, theta, psi):
    uav_size = 10  # Define the size of the UAV for visualization
    corners = np.array([
        [-uav_size/2, -uav_size/2, 0],  # Back-left
        [uav_size/2, -uav_size/2, 0],   # Back-right
        [uav_size/2, uav_size/2, 0],    # Front-right
        [-uav_size/2, uav_size/2, 0]    # Front-left
    ])
    center_of_mass = np.array([0, 0, 0])
    front_nose_line = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [uav_size/2, 0, 0]])  # Line from center to front

    R = rotation_matrix(phi, theta, psi)
    transformed_corners = np.array([R @ corner + np.array([x, y, z]) for corner in corners])
    transformed_center_of_mass = R @ center_of_mass + np.array([x, y, z])
    transformed_front_nose_line = np.array([R @ point + np.array([x, y, z]) for point in front_nose_line])

    return transformed_corners, transformed_center_of_mass, transformed_front_nose_line



# Create Plotly figure with 3D subplot
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1, specs=[[{'type': 'scatter3d'}]])

# Compute initial UAV shape
initial_corners, initial_center_of_mass, initial_front_nose_line = update_uav_shape(
    interp_x[0], interp_y[0], interp_z[0], interp_phi[0], interp_theta[0], interp_psi[0]
)

# Initialize the traces for UAV and Obstacle
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
    x=[], 
    y=[], 
    z=[], 
    mode='lines', 
    line=dict(color='blue', width=2), 
    name='UAV Path'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
    x=[interp_x[0]], 
    y=[interp_y[0]], 
    z=[interp_z[0]], 
    mode='markers', 
    marker=dict(size=5, color='blue'), 
    name='UAV Position'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(
    x=initial_corners[:, 0], 
    y=initial_corners[:, 1], 
    z=initial_corners[:, 2], 
    color='blue', 
    opacity=0.5, 
    name='UAV Shape'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
    x=initial_front_nose_line[:, 0], 
    y=initial_front_nose_line[:, 1], 
    z=initial_front_nose_line[:, 2], 
    mode='lines', 
    line=dict(color='yellow', width=4), 
    name='Front Nose'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
    x=[], 
    y=[], 
    z=[], 
    mode='lines', 
    line=dict(color='red', width=2), 
    name='Obstacle Path'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
    x=[interp_obs_x[0]], 
    y=[interp_obs_y[0]], 
    z=[interp_obs_z[0]], 
    mode='markers', 
    marker=dict(size=5, color='red'), 
    name='Obstacle Position'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[], y=[], z=[], mode='lines', line=dict(color='red', width=2), name='Obstacle Path'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[interp_obs_x[0]], y=[interp_obs_y[0]], z=[interp_obs_z[0]], mode='markers', marker=dict(size=5, color='red'), name='Obstacle Position'))

# Create frames to animate the markers and dynamically draw the trace paths
frames = []
for k in range(1, total_frames_uav):
    corners, center_of_mass, front_nose_line = update_uav_shape(interp_x[k], interp_y[k], interp_z[k], interp_phi[k], interp_theta[k], interp_psi[k])
    frame_data = [
        go.Mesh3d(x=corners[:, 0], y=corners[:, 1], z=corners[:, 2], color='blue', opacity=0.5),
        go.Scatter3d(x=interp_x[:k+1], y=interp_y[:k+1], z=interp_z[:k+1], mode='lines', line=dict(color='blue', width=2)),
        go.Scatter3d(x=[center_of_mass[0]], y=[center_of_mass[1]], z=[center_of_mass[2]], mode='markers', marker=dict(size=5, color='blue')),
        go.Scatter3d(x=front_nose_line[:, 0], y=front_nose_line[:, 1], z=front_nose_line[:, 2], mode='lines', line=dict(color='yellow', width=4))
    ]
    if k < total_frames_obstacle:
        frame_data.extend([
            go.Scatter3d(x=interp_obs_x[:k+1], y=interp_obs_y[:k+1], z=interp_obs_z[:k+1], mode='lines', line=dict(color='red', width=2)),
            go.Scatter3d(x=[interp_obs_x[k]], y=[interp_obs_y[k]], z=[interp_obs_z[k]], mode='markers', marker=dict(color='red', size=5))
        ])
    frames.append(go.Frame(data=frame_data, name=f'frame{k}'))

fig.frames = frames


# Add play and pause buttons
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[{
        'type': 'buttons',
        'buttons': [
            {'label': 'Play', 'method': 'animate', 'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 1000 / fps, 'redraw': True}, 'fromcurrent': True, 'transition': {'duration': 0, 'easing': 'linear'}}]},
            {'label': 'Pause', 'method': 'animate', 'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'mode': 'immediate', 'transition': {'duration': 0}}]}
        ],
        'direction': 'left',
        'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 87},
        'showactive': False,
        'x': 0.1,
        'xanchor': 'right',
        'y': 0,
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }]
)

# Set axis limits and display the figure
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(
    xaxis=dict(range=[0, 100], autorange=False),
    yaxis=dict(range=[0, 100], autorange=False),
    zaxis=dict(range=[0, 100], autorange=False),
    aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=1)
))

fig.show()

This is what i tried. I expect the UAV to "wait" or at least search for other maneuver, while waiting for the obstacle to move away from the landing coordinate (50,50,0) and then lands.

The reproducible example requires also the simulation_results.csv.

@Armali I can comment out these simulation_results.csv for initial guess and it will reproduce the example just fine. I have updated the code in the question. Thanks!

Caveat:  I didn't read all of your code or dive in too deep.
Suggestion:  You'll likely get better help on this/future questions if you can whittle down the question in some way to a minimal reproducible example.  This question kind of feels like you're looking for a research partner.  ;)
It appears you are doing something weird with your timescale and I'm not sure why 1 timescale isn't the right answer overall, but in this "helper function":
def scaled_time(m, t):
    return t * value(m.tf)

that you are using in your constraint for collisions you are asking for the value of m.tf.  I don't think you want to do that.  When you do that, you will retrieve the current value of the variable--before any solving activity.  Meaning:  It's just going to substitute in the initialization value as a constant (if provided, which you did).  If you intend for the variable to be a variable in the optimization, you should never ask for the value().  That's for post-solve.
If you are in the habit (you should be) of printing off the model with small/tiny data, you should see that problem if you m.pprint() or m.display()
If you intended for m.tf to be treated as the scalar 20 in this constraint, then this answer is off-track

I'm new to trajectory optimization, so I thought this was a basic and straightforward problem :D. You are exactly right, I want to keep m.tf as a variable, but this leads to an error. I have edited my question. Thanks for your reply!

I would try 2 things.  (I don't have much experience with dae etc.).  1.  just get rid of the function and compute scaled_time directly in the constraint body.  Perhaps the function is the issue.  2. (more likely) I'm concerned that you are multiplying a variable by a member of a continuous set.  (but as stated, not my area).  I'd gin up a side model with just a couple variables/continuous set and test that thesis out by trying to construct an expression or constraint.  Then, if that barfs, you have your minimal example for the next SO question.

I've tried using 't*m.tf' directly inside the constraint, but the same error occurs. Thanks for trying it out! I'm waiting for your reply!

lol.  "I'd gin up .... "  implies you doing it.

Hahah lol, alroght, thanks again tho
